# Anyone know why wordpress converts some html entities to their numeric equivalents?

Tags: posts, database, html

Does anyone know why wordpress converts some html entities to their numeric equivalents?

I've found that in some posts, where a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` entity would be appropriate, wordpress uses `&#160;` instead.

Seems to me that using the symbolic version of the entity would be better than a numeric version.

The routine that this is being done in (appears to be) ent2ncr in wp-includes/formatting.php.

When I converted my blog from a single site to multi-site (different install & database), the numeric entities were not converted properly (possibly due to a database difference).  Had the symbolic entities been used, I doubt this would have been a problem.

Comment: Ok so disregard last comment your post was edited when i was typing. That is a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In XHTML entities are not part of the DTD, and user agents are not required to support them. Exceptions: `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;`.

To keep WordPress X(HT)ML compatible numeric references are used instead.

Comment: That makes since. back to the old days instead i guess with that format.

Comment: Seems like a step backwards to me, but oh well.